# Upsert a csv file from a second file using bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a main csv file with records (file1). I then have a second "delta" csv file (file2). I would like to update the main file with the records from the delta file using bash. Existing records should get the new value (replace the row) and new records should be appended.

Example file1

```
unique_id|value  
'1'|'old'  
'2'|'old'  
'3'|'old'
```

Example file2

```
unique_id|value  
'1'|'new'  
'4'|'new'
```

Desired outcome

```
unique_id|value  
'1'|'new'  
'2'|'old'  
'3'|'old'  
'4'|'new'
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: what's the expected max size (MBytes, number of lines) of each file? is the first column always a quoted numeric or could it include non-numerics, too? assuming the result is to be sorted by the first column, are you looking to sort the first column as a string or as a numeric (eg, as string: `1`, `10`, `2` ...; as numeric `1`, `2`, ... `9`, `10`, `11` ...)? or is sorting not required?

Comment: are we always looking at just the two columns, or could there be more than two columns? are we always looking at just the first column as a pk (primary key) or could there be situations where the pk consists of multiple columns?

Comment: I will be having many variations of these file sets - as far as columns go. Generally they will be 5+. The format is always single quote around the column and pipe delimited. Some of these files can get to millions of records. I'm only building a POC now. I started looking at commands such as awk and sed and looping through the csv with `while read`.

Comment: `millions of records` means you don't want to do this in `bash` (ie, don't think about `while read` or any sort of `bash`/loop method) if you're looking for a solution with decent performance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' '
  ! ($1 in rows){ ids[id_count++] = $1 } 
  { rows[$1] = $0 } 
  END { 
      for(i=0; i<id_count; i++) 
          print rows[ids[i]] 
  }
' old.csv new.csv
```

Output:

```
unique_id|value
'1'|'new'
'2'|'old'
'3'|'old'
'4'|'new'
```

Similar approach using `perl`

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '
    $id = $F[0];
    push @ids, $id unless exists $rows{$id};
    $rows{$id} = $_;
    END { print $rows{$_} for @ids }
' old.csv new.csv
```

You could also use an actual database e.g. `sqlite`

```
sqlite> create table old (unique_id text primary key, value text);
sqlite> create table new (unique_id text primary key, value text);

# skip headers
sqlite> .sep '|'
sqlite> .import --skip 1 new.csv new 
sqlite> .import --skip 1 old.csv old

sqlite> select * from old;
'1'|'old'  
'2'|'old'  
'3'|'old'

sqlite> insert into old 
        select * from new where true 
        on conflict(unique_id) 
        do update set value=excluded.value;

sqlite> select * from old;
'1'|'new'  
'2'|'old'  
'3'|'old'
'4'|'new'
```

Comment: Thanks - this led me down a great path!

Answer (score 0):

I immediately thought of **join**, but you cannot specify "take this column if there's a match, otherwise use another column, *and* have either output end up in a *single* column".

For command-line processing of CSV files, I really like [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#introduction).  It has its own CSV-aware join command—which is also limited like join (above)—and it has other commands that we can chain together to produce the desired output.

GoCSV uses a streaming/buffered reader/writer for as many subcommands as it can.  Every command but **join** operates in this buffered-in-buffered-out fashion, but **join** needs to read both sides in total to match.  Still, GoCSV is compiled and just really, really fast.

All GoCSV commands read the delimiter to use from the `GOCSV_DELIMITER` environment variable, so your first order of business is to export that for your pipe delimiter:

```
export GOCSV_DELIMITER='|'
```

Joining is easy, just specify the columns from either file to use as the *key*.  I'm also going to rename the columns now so that we're set up for the conditional logic in the next step.  If your columns vary from file to file, you'll want to rename each set of columns first, before you join.

I'm telling **gocsv join** to pick the first columns from both files, `-c 1,1` and use an *outer* join to keep both left and right sides, regardless of match:

```
gocsv join -c 1,1 -outer file1.csv file2.csv \
| gocsv rename -c 1,2,3,4 -names 'id_left','val_left','id_right','val_right'
```

```
| id_left | val_left | id_right | val_right |
|---------|----------|----------|-----------|
| 1       | old      | 1        | new       |
| 2       | old      |          |           |
| 3       | old      |          |           |
|         |          | 4        | new       |
```

There's no way to change a value in an *existing* column based on another column's value, but we can *add* new columns and use a templating language to define the logic we need.

The following syntax creates two new columns, **id_final** and **val_final**.  For both columns, if there's a value in **val_right** that value is used, otherwise **val_left** is used.  This, cominbed with the outer-join of "left then right" from before, gives us the effect of the right side updating/overwriting the left side if the IDs matched:

```
... \
| gocsv add -name 'id_final'  -t '{{ if .id_right  }}{{ .id_right  }}{{ else }}{{ .id_left  }}{{ end }}' \
| gocsv add -name 'val_final' -t '{{ if .val_right }}{{ .val_right }}{{ else }}{{ .val_left }}{{ end }}'
```

```
| id_left | val_left | id_right | val_right | id_final | val_final |
|---------|----------|----------|-----------|----------|-----------|
| 1       | old      | 1        | new       | 1        | new       |
| 2       | old      |          |           | 2        | old       |
| 3       | old      |          |           | 3        | old       |
|         |          | 4        | new       | 4        | new       |
```

Finally, we can select just the "final" fields and rename them back to their original names:

```
... \
| gocsv select -c 'id_final','val_final' \
| gocsv rename -c 1,2 -names 'unique_id','value'
```

```
| unique_id | value |
|-----------|-------|
| 1         | new   |
| 2         | old   |
| 3         | old   |
| 4         | new   |
```

GoCSV has [pre-built binaries for modern platforms](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and run

```sh
mlr --csv --fs "|" join --ul --ur -j unique_id --lp "l@" --rp "r@"  -f 01.csv \
then put 'if(is_not_null(${r@value})){$value=${r@value}}else{$value=$value}' \
then cut -x -r -f '@' 02.csv
```

and I have

```
unique_id|value
'1'|'new'
'4'|'new'
'2'|'old'
'3'|'old'
```

I run a full join and I use an if condition, to check if I have value on the right. If I have it, I use it.